# how to get a value from a row in a GridView on Delete Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

See this Photo Plz
[Grid Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NX4Gz.png)

Here's the Delete button Function

```
    protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadButton btn = (RadButton)sender;
        GridDataItem data = (GridDataItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        string name= data["Name"].Text;

        Label1.Text = name;
     }
```

Comment: Seperate to any kind of answer - please don't store passwords in plain text, or EVER display them on screen like this.

Comment: Don't Worry my friend all data are fake and still on localhost :)

Comment: the data may be fake but the code presumably will go into production eventually? I recommend reading up on safe password storage.

Comment: So, what's the problem here exactly?

Comment: always return null

Comment: More information is needed to submit a full answer in my opinion. That being said, you should be able to get the ```DataContext``` from ```btn```. That will give you your object that you can extract the name from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need more information on what your model looks like to be 100% on this, but you should be able to get the `DataContext` from the clicked item.

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sendr = sender as RadioButton;
    if (sendr != null)
    {
        var clickedItem = sendr.DataContext as YourModel;
        if (clickedItem != null)
        {
            Label1.Text = clickedItem.Name;
        }
    }
}
```